# Cache for concurrent query

Tags: java, caching, concurrency

I have a cache class which is based on ConcurrentHashMap. This cache is used to store results I get from a relatively slow reference data service.

One problem of this is that, when multiple threads try to get a key that does not exist, both thread will go and fetch the same key from the reference data service, resulting in two reference data calls.

I am thinking to improve the implementation of the cache so that only one of the threads query the reference data service.

Is there any standard implementation for this?

Comment: google `memoizer ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: There are lightweight caches, like Goggle Guava cache or [cache2k](http://cache2k.org), which have the desired behavior by default.
In Guava you need to do a LoadingCache, in cache2k you need to define a cache source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code which stores the unique keys in a List<> keyLocks and if a object with the equivalent value is passed it will return the same key for it, and then a synchroized block on the key

```
private final List<Object> keyLocks = new ArrayList<>(); // field in Cache




   public Object get(Object key){
      Object lock;
      synchronized (keyLocks) {
        if (!keyLocks.contains(key)) {
           keyLocks.add(key);
           lock = key;
        } else {
           lock = keyLocks.get(keyLocks.indexOf(key));
        }
      }
      synchronized (lock) {
         if(innerCache.containsKey(key)){
            return cache.get(key);
         }else{
            Object result = dataService.get(key);
            innerCache.put(key,result);
            return result;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: You are assuming that they are accessing with the same actual key. What if they are accessing with two equal keys?